# Can I disable cashing audio, video files on SSHD

Tags: video, hybrid-storage

My Win10 i5-5200 2,2GHz with RAM-8Gb becomes very slow :)

I have 100Gb data on HDD in my notebook. So, replace HDD with SSD-256Gb would be more than enough for me.

Another choice for the same price is hybrid SSHD with SSD-128Gb and HDD-500Gb. I would prefer this choice and will use spare part of SSHD to store audio/video files.
Can I disable audio/video cashing on SSD part? Is it a problem?

Comment: Shouldn't be an issue, the SSHD should be storing the most frequently used files in the SSD part so, it shouldn't matter.

Comment: It depends, I believe on the shdd. By default you don't get to choose what is stored where, but some will allow you to do this by presenting the shdd as 2 different devices when using some drivers.